# How to emulate php CURL request on server? CURL request blocked from server but not from localhost

Tags: php, curl, server, httprequest, hosting

I wrote a script to request information from a remote website. I debugged everything locally and deployed to server.

Everything run smoothly on my localhost until I loaded to the server where the curl_execute wasn't able to connect to the target host. I debugged with another URL and it worked so I guess there is no configurations needed from the server side. I am guessing the target host denies or something a response to the request - I just don't know how nor why.

This is the code I use to make the request.

```
ch = curl_init();
    $http_headers = array(
                    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2',
                    'Connection: keep-alive',
                    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124'
                  );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $targetURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

What can I do to emulate a 'normal' request and avoid being denied by the target host? Any tips, appreciated.

Regards

Comment: you're specifying two different user-agents. that's rather pointless. "I'm a mac! I'm a PC" ... even in tv commercials they had to use two different actors for that...

Comment: Did you ssh into your server and try a command line curl to the url in question form there?

Comment: Not answerable without a guess list. What actual error message does "wasn't able to connect" refer to? At least use CURLOPT_VERBOSE, compare against the local setup and browser headers. Else consult the admin of the target site.

Comment: "error:connect() timed out!" - this is the error message. I will check the verbose of localhost (which works) vs server (which doesn't) vs regular browser in my computer. Do you think, by comparing all headers, ill be able to replicate settings? Based on what can the target host determine that the requests shouldn't be attended?

Comment: Marc B - I took care of the user-agent. Problem persists.